# When should I introduce a reference?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am currently writing my research proposal and I have a piece where I quote a book. In summary I am saying the following:

> Mr. X says that there is a very high probability that squares have four sides. This can be concisely summarised as "*a polygon with four sides*". ...

*Note that at the end I am quoting him directly.*

When do I put a citation to Mr. X’s book?

- Immediately after the first sentence.
- At the end, when I stop referring to him in the paragraph, i.e., after the second sentence or later.
- Both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer: This is my opinion**

I can think of a couple ways:

First, edit the first sentence so that it does not require a reference:

> It has been postulated that squares are very probable to have four
>   sides. For instance, Mr. X concisely summarised that ‘a polygon with
>   four sides’... (Ref)

Second, chain the sentences together, eliminating the period:

> Mr. X, a main proponent who suggests that there is a very high
>   probability that squares have four sides, concisely summarised that ‘a
>   polygon with four sides’... (Ref)

Or

> Mr. X says that there is a very high probability that squares have
>   four sides: he summarised that ‘a polygon with four sides’... (Ref)

Third, keep the current structure.

I think it's acceptable to cite only once if you can keep the subjects consistent:

> Mr. X says that there is a very high probability that squares have
>   four sides. He concisely summarised that ‘a polygon with four sides’...
>   (Ref)

The fact that the first subject is "Mr. X" and then the second subject became "This (idea)" causes the disjoint feeling. Unifying the subjects will leave no room for misinterpretation.